# Алгоритм перевода предложения

Tags: vb.net, алгоритм, .net

Здравствуйте. Хочу создать переводчик предложений. Сразу хочу отметить, что языка для которого я пишу программу нет в готовых переводчиков (не предлагать готовые онлайн или софт-переводчики). Есть только база слов, из них нужно создать предложение максимально схожее с вводимым предложением(для перевода). Заранее спасибо!
Пригодится любая помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то думал заниматься, но руки так и не дошли.

На мой взгляд, начать с определения частей речи - т.е. в базе слов с переводами добавить признаки "глагол", "прилагательное" и так далее.

Далее думаю, стоит двигаться в направлении изучения падежей - т.е., например, в русском языке, подлежащее обычно в именительном падеже (Кто/Что?) - это поможет выделить части предложения в исходном предложении. Изучить согласование имен существительных и глаголов (по родам) - это уже позволит переводить простые предложения вида "Вася ушел", изучить согласование имен существительных и прилагательных ("Пьяный Вася ушел"), изучить использование предлогов к, в, на..... и существительных в качестве обстоятельства места... Гм, очень много работы не столько программиста, сколько лингвиста...

Попытаться изучить структуру предложений на целевом языке - т.е., например, в английском - подлежащее-сказуемое-дополнения. Если есть жестко заданная целевая структура - все просто - только выделить нужные части предложения на исходном языке и поставить их в нужные места в целевом, плюс согласовать числа/залоги/времена/роды....

Короче не все так просто как кажется... Но - удачи Вам!